# Visual Studio Code Symfony 3 namespaces autosuggestions

Tags: visual-studio, symfony, namespaces, autosuggest

I'd like to use Visual Studio Code to work with Symfony 3 and angular 2.
In VSC I've installed "PHP IntelliSense" package but this not suggesting all. For example when I type:

```
use Doctrine\
```

and now I'm pressing Ctrl+space VCS is suggesting only

> Bundle {}
>
> Common {}

namespaces, none ORM or other namespaces in doctrine bundle.

Which packets should I install to work with Symfony with full of suggestions? That suggestions are in NetBeans but I'd prefer VSC - it's nicer

Thanks in advance

Comment: use https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

Comment: phpstorm its not free, I'm not proffesinal programmer. I just learn now

Comment: there is a sublime plugin https://github.com/raulfraile/sublime-symfony2

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is disable VS Code's built-in PHP IntelliSense by going to Settings -> php.suggest.basic to avoid conflicts.
[image: Vscode settings]

Answer (score 0):

I have just found [A simple package that's provides useful snippets for the latest versions of Symfony](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Cronos87.symfony-snippets) in the marketplace.

Right now, it has this functionalities:

-Create a new action function
-Get a container
-Controller Template
-Create the Entity Manager Variable
-Throw an Access Denied Exception
-Throw a Not Found Exception
-Forward to an another controller/action
-Return a json response 
-Get a parameter value from the parameter file
-Return a redirect response using a route name
-Return a redirect response 
-Return a view
-Retrieve a repository
-Get the session object
-Dump a variable using the Symfony's one